# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int even though it's BigInt

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert a row in the table which throws an Arithmetic overflow error. However, I am having difficulty understanding the reason !

```
Here's the table Columns- 
        [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [batch_number] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [mixer_batch_history_id] [int] NULL,
        [lab_test_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [lab_test_compound_id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [machine_number] [int] NULL,
        [sample_location_id] [int] NULL,
        [sample_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [pass_customer_specs] [int] NOT NULL,
        [pass_internal_specs] [int] NOT NULL,
        [tested_by] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
        [last_test] [bit] NULL,
        [date_created] [datetime] NOT NULL
```

I am trying the following query -

```
DECLARE @batchNo as BIGINT = 2010000976009

INSERT INTO [LoMOS].dbo.lab_test
            (batch_number, mixer_batch_history_id, lab_test_type_id, lab_test_compound_id, machine_number, sample_location_id, sample_date, pass_customer_specs, pass_internal_specs, date_created)
     VALUES (@batchNo,  16579,  1,  128,    1,  1,  '2020-07-06 08:43:25.227',  0,  1,  '2020-07-08 07:44:27.993')
     SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Which Throws an Error as -

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: I created a table with your definition, and successfully ran your insert script.  Can you double-check?

Comment: Does the table have a trigger?

Comment: Thank you for posting code and some DDL. Your code works fine if I actually add a `create table` statement. However, there may be other factors involved, like constraints or triggers. Anything like that we're not seeing here?

Comment: Yes, It was a trigger Indeed ! I forgot to make sure that the batch number column should be BIGINT in trigger as well. The misunderstanding often happens as I have 2 tables on 2 different servers with same name but one being big int and another being int as a type of batch_number column ! Thanks so much @allmhuran

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, it seems highly likely the error is coming from a trigger, not the insert as posted.